# Trusts - Active Directory - 0xc000019b

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

So I'am getting the follow error when try validate the trust between to active directory (on internal, other external)

> The outgoing trust was successfully validated.
>
> The secure channel (SC) reset on Active Directory Domain Controller
> \FQDN of domain FQDN to domain FQDN failed with error: There are
> currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
>
> The log from dcdiag: The Security System detected an authentication
> error for the server cifs/fqdn. The failure code from authentication
> protocol Kerberos was "The name or SID of the domain specified is
> inconsistent with the trust information for that domain.
>
> (0xc000019b)".

Nothing is blocking in firewall, can ping external fqdn, user and password are correct

Any idea?

Comment: is reverse dns working properly?  Do either of the entities have additional trusts?

Comment: `The name or SID of the domain specified is inconsistent with the trust information for that domain.` What changed with the other trusted domain?

Answer (score 0):

There is name overlapping in trust information that each forest already has. Are there any other trusts that they have different from this one?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/name-suffix-routing

As resolution: wildcard name suffix routing entries should be checked and exact name-suffix routing entries should be set as per the article.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).